# truth tables with /~ in J

Tags: j

I was experimenting with generating truth tables in J:

```
    nand =: *:
    nand /~ 0 1
1 1
1 0
    bxor =: 22 b.  NB. Built-in bitwise XOR
    bxor /~ 0 1
0 1
1 0
```

Now I want to define my own logical xor, which I did like so:

```
    xor =: 3 : 0
]y                     NB. monadic case is just the identity
:
(x*.-.y)+.(y*.-.x)     NB. dyadic case is (x AND NOT y) OR (y AND NOT x)
)
```

This works as I expect when I call it directly.

```
    0 xor 0 1
0 1
    1 xor 0 1
1 0
```

But it doesn't generate a truth table:

```
    xor /~ 0 1
0 0
```

Why not?

I thought maybe the problem was that `]/~ 0 1` itself produced a 1 x 2 array, so I changed the monadic part to use nand (`*:y`) because it produces the 2x2 array:

```
    *:/~ 0 1
1 1
1 0


   xor =: 3 : 0
*:y                  NB. certainly wrong, but at least has 2x2 shape.
:
(x*.-.y)+.(y*.-.x)
)
```

But I still get the same behavior:

```
    xor /~ 0 1
0 0
```

Can someone help me understand the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: **Update:** I found `~:`, which implements logical XOR, and `~:/~ 0 1` builds the truth table correctly... But I still don't understand why my hand-coded one doesn't play nice with `/~`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `xor` has infinite rank, while `*:`,`~:` have rank 0. You can verify that by using [b.](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dbdotu.htm): `v b. 0` like so:

```
~: b. 0
  _ 0 0 

*: b. 0
  0 0 0

xor b. 0
  _ _ _
```

What this means is that `xor` operates on the list `0 1` rather than on each individual atom `0`, `1`.

You will get the result you expect if you use `xor` with rank 0:

```
xor"0 /~ 0 1
0 1
1 0
```

Or if you define `xor` to be of rank 0.

Comment: See [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/07.htm) and [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/loopless_code_i_verbs_have_r.htm) for ranks. The `v b. 0` above gives the rank for monadic, dyadic-left, dyadic-right case of the verb `v`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I'd been trying to understand what `"` did, too. Now I'm starting to see the pieces fit together. :)